# Flutter in_app_purchase handle subscription lifecycle

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I am using `in_app_purchase: ^2.0.1` and thinking how to handle the whole lifecycle of subscription product. This is what I've found out:

- `purchaseStream` is triggered when user buy non-consumable product
- `purchaseStream` is not triggered after app restart
- `purchaseStream` is not triggered when user pause or cancel subscription
- `purchaseStream` is not triggered when subscription expire

this is the default behavior, but there is also `restorePurchases()` method, when I call it then:

- `purchaseStream` is triggered ONLY when the subscription is valid
- `purchaseStream` is not triggered when the subscription is canceled, expired, or paused

I am thinking about these approaches

#### 1) client app only

- when user buy -> store somewhere the purchaseID, hash, whatever.
- when user opens the app again, call `restorePurchases()` and wait for let's say 5 seconds
- if there is no value in the `purchaseStream` I guess that the subscription is invalid
- if there is value, just compare ID and hash against the database

#### 2) + server side (probably preferable)

- the `purchaseStream` is used just for the current purchase, not for the future updates
- `recoverPurchases` is not called
- when user buy -> store somewhere the purchaseID + calculate and store date until
- create some kind of cron job which checks users who have older date until
- this job should get the details based on purchaseID but where/how*?
- when the purchase is still valid, skip, when not, remove the subscription from the db

#### 3) some kind of combination of these above

Thanks for your ideas ;)

Comment: Hi there! I found it via Google. Did you tried it? I think the only thing that doesn't sound good is about the trial period. If you give some a trial period of, for example, 5 days, the subscription token will change without updating the database.
Furthermore the server-side solution will give the "premium features" to everyone will got the account login details, so this will be not so useful

Comment: Any luck here? I'm a little stumped on how to really know if a subscription is canceled or expired. The listener doesn't fire so I'm unsure of what to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the user purchase event, calc and save locally last subscription date (with shared_preferences). And on every app start compare current date ws stored. If less - user subscribed, if not - subscription is expired.